# Insert squares into mat-table - Angular

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-material

I have problem with mat-table. I need to insert the square in to the cells but I don't know it.

This is my code now.

```
<div class="my_item">
        <div><span class="skuska"><span class="mat-subheading-2">Január</span></span></div>
        <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column.id}}" *ngFor="let column of columnNames">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{column.value}} </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element[column.id]}} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
          <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>
      </div>
```

And this is running code ... I have only text in the table, and i need add the squares with numbers instead the text.

My running code:

[image]

I have only picture example of table with squares

Table with squares:

[image]

Can you help me please?

Thank you so much !

Now I have that ->

[image: Actual]

Html file

```
 <div class="my_item">
        <div><span class="skuska"><span class="mat-subheading-2">Apríl</span></span></div>
        <mat-table #table [dataSource]="dataSource" matSort>
          <ng-container matColumnDef="{{column.id}}" *ngFor="let column of columnNames">
            <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header> {{column.value}} </mat-header-cell>
            <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element" [style.background-color] = "element.color"> {{element[column.id]}} </mat-cell>
          </ng-container>

          <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
          <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
        </mat-table>
      </div>
```

.ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { MatTableDataSource, MatSort } from '@angular/material';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-harmonogram',
  templateUrl: './harmonogram.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./harmonogram.component.css']
})
export class HarmonogramComponent implements OnInit {

  dataSource;
  displayedColumns = [];
  @ViewChild(MatSort) sort: MatSort;

  /**
   * Pre-defined columns list for user table
   */
  columnNames = [{
    id: "po",
    value: "po"

  }, {
    id: "ut",
    value: "ut"
  }, {
    id: "st",
    value: "st"
  }, {
    id: "stv",
    value: "št"
  }, {
    id: "pi",
    value: "pi"
  }, {
    id: "so",
    value: "so"
  }, {
    id: "ne",
    value: "ne"
  }];

  ngOnInit() {
    this.displayedColumns = this.columnNames.map(x => x.id);
    this.createTable();
  }

  createTable() {
    let tableArr: Element[] =
      [
        { po: '', ut: '', st: '', stv: '', pi: '', so: '', ne: '',color: 'black'},
      { po: '', ut: '', st: '', stv: '', pi: '', so: '', ne: '',color: 'green'},
      { po: '', ut: '', st: '', stv: '', pi: '', so: '', ne: '',color: 'grey'},
      { po: '', ut: '', st: '', stv: '', pi: '', so: '', ne: '',color: 'blue'},
        { po: '', ut: '', st: '', stv: '', pi: '', so: '', ne: '',color: 'green'}
      ];
    this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(tableArr);
    this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
  }
}

export interface Element {
  po: string,
  ut: string,
  st: string,
  stv: string,
  pi: string,
  so: string,
  ne: string,
  color: string,
}
```

And this is part of .css file

```
.mat-cell{

  height: 26px;
  width: 26px;
  display: inline-flex;
  border-left: 4px solid white;
  padding-left: 0px;
}
```

I can change only the row color.. but i need change the specific cells, e.g. with value "8" (now the numbers of cells are invisible)

Comment: have you read about https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle ?

Comment: can you create a minimal demo with :https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material

Comment: No sorry, I am new in angular. Can you tell me something more about that ? Classes are in .HTML, or .TS?

Comment: remove th temlate code of stackblitz and add yours

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-pq3m31?embed=1&file=app/app.component.html - this is mine. but it have errors when i copy mine code instead the stackblitz code.

Comment: put your ts code also and click on fork button then attacj your link

Comment: The code is in html link, click in the left panel for the show the all classes

Comment: isn't it? But thank you very much :)

Comment: I show and try to fix errors

Comment: You are very good woman! O:)

Comment: woman:).........

Comment: Edited O:) Sorry

Comment: do you want text and color in squares or only squares??

Comment: numbers of days in specific colour in squares ... eg ... days 1 - 31. will be grey without days 5,6,7 which will be green ...

Comment: Please don't invalidate your question, I rolled back your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this in css:

See here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d2yrwq-yfwgrf?file=app/table-basic-example.css

```
.mat-cell{
    background-color: green;
    min-height: 26px;
    border-left: 4px solid white;
    padding-left: 9px;
}
.mat-cell:last-child{
     background: linear-gradient(90deg, green 50%, white 50%);
}
```

For dinamic `background-color` use `[style.backgound]="YourColor"`

and if it `last-child` (means `element[column.id]='ne'`) use `[style.backgound]="linear-gradient(90deg, 50%, YourColor white 50%)"`

**See here**:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d2yrwq-bdnuwy?file=app/table-basic-example.html

Comment: tell me for more help

Comment: So when I want to change color of the specific cell, i need to use the e.g - last-child method?

Comment: no last-child it because the last element in each row behave diffrent then all row try to remove `last-child` and see what append

Comment: use `[style.backgound]="YourColor"` in selector

Comment: Okey, so how i can change color of the specific cells ? e.g in the first table with cell values 1,3,6,8 will be black color, and the remaining will be green

Comment: see here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50963302/how-to-set-background-color-by-angular-bound-value/50963452#50963452

Comment: so how i use `<div [ngStyle]="{'background-color':tile.color}" style="border-style: solid;width: 150px;height: 150px;" class="tile">{{tile.name}}</div>` in html ? And then in css or ?

Comment: hey see here:https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-d2yrwq-bdnuwy?file=app/table-basic-example.html

Comment: Thanks you so much!

Comment: Happy to help :)

Comment: And the last one, any idea how i can align the values into the middle of the square?

Comment: Only with padding in css? Or do you know something much better?

Comment: What should I do to not change the size of squares when I am resizing the page?